# Why adding a [ ] to json string worked and why it was not working earlier

Tags: c#, json

Below is  my json string which was there in .txt file,

```
{"SerialNumber":"1","Festival":"New Year","Day":"Friday"}
```

When I tried to consume  it from code behind(C#) file by below line

```cs
List<PublicHolidayObj> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PublicHolidayObj>>(json);
```

I was getting error (deserialize json sting to generic list), But later on where i added a [ ] to json , it worked and i could able to see the name:values got populated in list.

Example:

```
[{"SerialNumber":"1","Festival":"New Year","Day":"Friday"}]
```

So is it mandatory for a json string to be a array always to get consumed by a C# list object ? I Could not able to differentiate the difference before adding [ ] and without it.

Comment: *"deserialize json sting to genric list"* `[]` is a list, `{}` is a single object

Answer (score 10):

Quite simply, your first JSON represents a single object. Your second JSON represents an array with a single element.

You can't deserialize a single element to a list, because it *isn't* a list.

You should be able to deserialize your first JSON to just a single object like this:

```
PublicHolidayObj item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PublicHolidayObj>(json);
```

> So is it mandatory for a json string to be a array always to get consumed by a C# list object ?

Yes, you can't treat a single object as a list, because it's not a list - just as you wouldn't expect this code to compile:

```
PublicHolidayObj item = new PublicHolidayObj();
// This won't compile, because a single item isn't a list of items.
List<PublicHolidayObj> items = item;
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `[]` you've made a JSON array, which is why it will deserialize into a list.

```cs
singleItem = {"SerialNumber":"1","Festival":"New Year","Day":"Friday"}

array = [
  {"SerialNumber":"1","Festival":"New Year","Day":"Friday"},
  {"SerialNumber":"2","Festival":"Christmas","Day":"Thursday"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Generally json starts with `{}` (curly bracket), but here it is like `[]` (square bracket).

This is because you got an array of objects, not a single object. Arrays are serialized with square brackets around them. You should deserialize it into an array, and then grab the object at the index of interest.